# jquery autocomplete ajax return object instead of name

Tags: jquery

MY JSP FILE:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-7 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="autoComplt" class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-5 control-label">Auto Complete : </label>
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-7">
            <input id="autoComplt" type ="text" name="autoComplt" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

MY JS FILE:

```
var availableTags = [];

$.ajax({
  url: contextPath + "/branchMst/findDistinctBranch.html",
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
      availableTags.push(this.toString());
    });
    return availableTags;
  }
});

$("#autoComplt").autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

### OUTPUT :

object1
object 2

Comment: What does `data` look like from your GET? Console log `data` just before you return availableTags. It should be JSON, so you probably need to pass `function(i)` into the `.each()` and refer to it with `data[i]`.

Comment: number of results are wright but in the object form please do some help